# Hide a Label if a property is false in WIX

Tags: wix, wix3.8

I have a WIX Project consisting of some wxs files.In my one wxs file namely "DBFile" I want to hide one label say "lbl" at runtime depending upon the Properties.
i.e. If my property say "IsDbExists" is true then i want to show label "lbl" otherwise it should be hidden.

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
<Control Id="LoginTextBox" Type="Edit" ...>
  <Condition Action="hide" >IsDbExists&lt;&gt;1</Condition>
  <Condition Action="show" >IsDbExists=1</Condition>
</Control>
```